# In typescript, error on array that includes index signature

Tags: typescript

When change object's type to Generic array with `as`, I found an error.

```js
interface TestType {
    action: TestGeneric<number>[]
}
type TestGeneric<T> = {
    [key: string]: T
}

const func = () => {
    const Test = {
        action: [
            { a: 3 },
            { e: 4 }
        ]
    }
    console.log(Test as TestType)
}
```

error message is:

> Conversion of type '{ action: ({ a: number; e?: undefined; } | { e: number; a?: undefined; })[]; }' to type 'TestType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Types of property 'action' are incompatible.
> Type '({ a: number; e?: undefined; } | { e: number; a?: undefined; })[]' is not comparable to type 'TestGeneric[]'.
> Type '{ a: number; e?: undefined; } | { e: number; a?: undefined; }' is not comparable to type 'TestGeneric'.
> Type '{ e: number; a?: undefined; }' is not comparable to type 'TestGeneric'.
> Property 'a' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'undefined' is not comparable to type 'number'.

If I declare with type (`Test: TestType = ...`) or use `unknown` keyword, No error throw.
But I want to import local json file. Type check is important to me.

tsconfig.json is: (same as Create-React-App)

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

edit: Generic wasn't the real problem. It seems that the real problem was the problem with the array and index signature. [link](https://tsplay.dev/Wo14jN)

```
() => {
    const test = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
    type TestType = {[key: string]: number}[]

    console.log(test as TestType);
}
```

error message is:

> Conversion of type '({ a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; })[]' to type 'TestType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Type '{ a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; }' is not comparable to type '{ [key: string]: number; }'.
> Type '{ b: number; a?: undefined; }' is not comparable to type '{ [key: string]: number; }'.
> Property 'a' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'undefined' is not comparable to type 'number'.

second edit: I changed data types `array` to index signature. [link](https://tsplay.dev/mqqzZm)

```
() => {
    const test = {0:{a: 1}, 1: {b: 2}}
    type TestType = {[key: string]: {[key: string]: number}}

    console.log(test as TestType);
}
```

After reading the answer, I understood that data types should be declared separately. So what's different about this code from before? Why doesn't this code throw an error?

Comment: I don't see any errors when I [copy and paste your code into the TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRPxLm).

Comment: Type assertions can complain if the relationship between the two types isn't direct enough. Your array literal undergoes [object literal normalization](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals) which introduced `undefined`, which is not compatible with your index signature. If you really want to use type assertions sometimes you will need to take multiple steps, such as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/NVr0qN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn disable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` option to see error, [link](https://tsplay.dev/Wo14jN)  but I will enable this option. Thank you.

Comment: @jcalz sorry. Now I remember why I thought this was a problem. I will supplement the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a type script, because you have no types in the function, typescript need to guess and this is sometimes not possible.

The following would work:

```
const func = (): void => {
  const a: TestGeneric<number> = { a: 3 };
  const b: TestGeneric<number> = { b: 3 };
  const test = {
    action: [a, b]
  }
  console.log(test as TestType)
}
```

or this

```
const func = (): void => {
  const test = {
    action: [
      { ['a']: 3 } as TestGeneric<number>,
      { ['e']: 4 }
    ]
  }
  console.log(test as TestType)
}
```

or this

```
const func = (): void => {
  const action: TestGeneric<number>[] = [{ ['a']: 3 }, { ['e']: 4 }];
  const test = {
    action,
  };
  console.log(test as TestType);
};
```

As soon there is no need to guess, typescript is happy.